# slideshow using overlapping transparent images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have looked at the very helpful suggestions for the css for handling a bunch of exactly overlapping transparent images placed on a non-transparent image (in my case, a map but not a google-type map, just a line drawing). Could someone help me with turning that into a slideshow? I want to progressively stack images directly on top of each other so that the user sees an accumulation of visual information.

Comment: This sounds like it will require JavaScript. I'm tagging your question with it. I'm also going to guess that you don't mind using jQuery, so I'm also tagging it with that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simplified implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/r7B4n/

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#showNext').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#slideShow li:hidden:first').fadeIn();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideShow {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff)
}
#slideShow li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    display: none
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="slideShow">
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCTLO.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm25l.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rtc5.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg3MF.png" /></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="showNext">Show next image</a>
```